# How to use Multiple Tables in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, model

I have worked with CI 3 so far and would like to address several database tables separately (no joins) in a new model (in CI 4).

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;


class MyModel extends Model {

  protected $table = 'main_table';

  public function getAll($uid = false) {

    return $this->where(['hidden' => '0'])
                ->where(['deleted' => '0'])
                ->findAll();

  }


  public function getMainImage($pid) {

    return $this->from('another_table')
                ->where(['pid' => $pid])
                ->findAll();

  }


 }
```

For some reason the whole thing doesn't seem to work out.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error, but it seems like CI uses both tables (main_table and another_table). I only want to use the second one.

Comment: in getMainImage try to set $this->table="another_table" than no need of from, but problem is if you call getAll after this i will query another_table because table name already set.

Comment: Unfortunately with this CI only looks at the "main_table" and ignores "another_table" completely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instanciate the db connection again and assign the second table to that variable inside the function, like this:

```
public function getMainImage($pid) {
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('secondary_table');
    
    return $builder->where(['pid' => $pid])
         ->get()->getResult();
}
```

More information on how to use the query builder here:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder

Comment: Are you sure? This produces a "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::table()" error

Comment: @Tom I edited the answer to add the complete function structure to what you need.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro What do you mean? With the answer given here, I still get the error "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::table()"

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Thx, but now it's "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::findAll() "

Comment: @Tom should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I have alternate approach to consume multiple tables in CI4 exploiting `Model->db` property. I would assign `another_table` builder to protected property (optionally I can use `Model.initialize()` to revoke on load) in the desired  function (in this case `getMainImage`)

```
<?php

class MyModel extends Model
{
  protected $DBGroup = 'TBGroup';
  protected $table = 'main_table';
  protected $table_another_table = null;

  // optional preload
  function initialize()
  {
    $this->table_another_table = $this->db->table('another_table');
  }

  public function getAll($uid = false)
  {

    return $this->where(['hidden' => '0'])
      ->where(['deleted' => '0'])
      ->findAll();
  }


  public function getMainImage($pid)
  {
    // Optionally preload in initialize method
    $this->table_another_table = $this->db->table('another_table');
    return $this->table_secondary
      ->where(['pid' => $pid])
      ->findAll();
  }
}
```

`Model->DBGroup` property is important in this case.